# Executar uma função em um tempo determinado

Tags: c#, .net, timer, task

Bom dia, recentemente estou a querer executar um método que faz o envio de mails do tipo newsletter de tempos em tempos. Acredito ter encontrado a solução, porem não consigo por ela em pratica que é a seguinte:

```
/****************************************************************************
*
*                         Agendador de Tarefas
*
*  Desenvolvido por Lucas Phillip
*
/***************************************************************************/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyTimers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Cria uma nova agenda.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="horario"></param>
    class Scheduler
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, Scheduler> SchedulePool = new Dictionary<string, Scheduler>();

        private System.Threading.Timer scheculetimer;
        private StartTime start;
        private TimerCallback MethodCallBack;
        private TimeSpan frequencia;
        private int maxexec = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Define ou Retorna o ID da tarefa
        /// </summary>
        public String ID { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Define ou Retorna a frequência com que a tarefa se repete após sua primeira execução.
        /// Utilize timespan(0) para não repetir
        /// </summary>
        public TimeSpan Frequencia { get { return frequencia; } set { frequencia = value; } }
        /// <summary>
        /// Retorna o número de vezes que que o método foi executado
        /// </summary>
        public int CountExec { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Define ou Retorna o número máximo de vezes para executar a tarefa
        /// </summary>
        public int MaxExec { get { return maxexec; } set { maxexec = value; } }
        /// <summary>
        /// Define ou Retorna o objeto Timer da tarefa
        /// </summary>
        public System.Threading.Timer ScheduleTimer { get { return scheculetimer; } set { scheculetimer = value; } }

        public Scheduler(TimerCallback Method)
        {
            MethodCallBack = Method;
        }

        public class StartTime
        {
            public int Hour { get; set; }
            public int Minutes { get; set; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adiciona uma nova tarefa que será executada determidado horário
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="State"></param>
        /// <param name="Execute"></param>
        public void AddSchedule(object State, StartTime horario)
        {
            start = horario;
            if (ID != null)
            {
                TimerCallback method = new TimerCallback(Loop);
                ScheduleTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(method, State, StartDelay(), Frequencia);

                SchedulePool.Add(ID, this);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("É preciso definir um ID para a tarefa!");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adiciona uma tarefa que será executada depois de um delay
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="State"></param>
        /// <param name="Delay"></param>
        public void StartWithDelay(object State, TimeSpan Delay)
        {
            if (ID != null)
            {
                TimerCallback method = new TimerCallback(Loop);
                ScheduleTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(method, State, Delay, Frequencia);

                SchedulePool.Add(ID, this);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("É preciso definir um ID para a tarefa!");
            }
        }

        private void Loop(object State)
        {
            //Adicinona +1 à contagem de vezes que a tarefa foi executada
            CountExec++;
            if (MaxExec > 0)
            {
                if (CountExec > MaxExec)
                {
                    Dispose();
                    return;
                }
            }

            //Invoca o metedo
            MethodCallBack.Invoke(State);

            //Confere se a tarefa se repete. Se não repetir libera a memória
            if (Frequencia.Ticks == 0)
            {
                Dispose();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retorna um TimeSpan com o dalay inicial, baseado na data agendada
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private TimeSpan StartDelay()
        {
            //Define os minutos antes de definir a hora, pois aqueles podem influenciar nestes
            int waitminute = GetMinutes();
            int waithour = GetHour();
            return new TimeSpan(waithour, waitminute, 0);
        }

        private int GetMinutes()
        {
            if (start.Minutes > DateTime.Now.Minute)
            {
                return start.Minutes - DateTime.Now.Minute;
            }
            else
            {
                start.Hour--;
                return start.Minutes - DateTime.Now.Minute + 60;
            }
        }

        private int GetHour()
        {
            if (start.Hour > DateTime.Now.Hour)
            {
                return start.Hour - DateTime.Now.Hour;
            }
            else if (start.Hour < DateTime.Now.Hour)
            {
                return start.Hour - DateTime.Now.Hour + 24;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            ScheduleTimer.Dispose();
            if (SchedulePool.ContainsKey(ID))
                SchedulePool.Remove(ID);
        }

        public class Control
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Retorna a referencia para a tarefa
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="ScheduleId"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static Scheduler GetTimer(String ScheduleId)
            {
                if (SchedulePool.ContainsKey(ScheduleId))
                {
                    return SchedulePool[ScheduleId];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("A tarefa especificada para cancelar não existe");
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Cancela a tarefa atual
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="ScheduleId"></param>
            public static void Cancel(String ScheduleId)
            {
                Scheduler schedule = GetTimer(ScheduleId);
                schedule.Dispose();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adiciona um int à quantidade máxima de execuções. Se não houver limite, define um.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="ScheduleId"></param>
            /// <param name="Times"></param>
            public static void AddExec(String ScheduleId, int Times)
            {
                Scheduler schedule = GetTimer(ScheduleId);
                schedule.MaxExec += Times;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Executa o método agendado.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="ScheduleId"></param>
            /// <param name="State"></param>
            public static void Execute(String ScheduleId, object State)
            {
                Scheduler schedule = GetTimer(ScheduleId);
                schedule.MethodCallBack.Invoke(State);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tenho o problema de como fazer o chamado da função que executa o envio dos email. Estou fazendo tentando executar com o código:

```
Scheduler task = new Scheduler(enviaNewsletter);
            task.ID = "EnviaNewsletter";
            task.Frequencia = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
            task.MaxExec = 2;

Scheduler.ControlScheduler.Execute("EnviaNewsletter",1);
```

E minha função é a seguinte:

```
public void enviaNewsletter(Object state)
        {
            Conteúdo...
        }
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar tentei de varias maneiras mas sem resultado então por enquanto parei por aqui.

Comment: Mas qual é o problema?

Comment: Respondi o que é a melhor resposta para você, fora isto, sem mais detalhes, não dá para ajudar. Olhando por cima parece que está ok mas nem sei o que deveria fazer de fato.

Comment: O problema que ele não executa minha função, Vai para o else do GetTimer

Comment: A classe `Scheduler` *não* tem propriedade `ControlScheduler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu sei que não é bem o que você quer mas a solução para isto é criar uma [tarefa agendada no sistema operacional](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#1TC=windows-7) que execute a aplicação que deseja. Não tem porque ficar reinventando a roda.

Saiba que não é algo trivial e tem uma quantidade enorme de detalhes que programadores não especialistas terão muita dificuldade.

Mas se quer insistir pelo menos use uma biblioteca que faz o grosso o trabalho por você. Algumas delas:

- [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) - acredito ser a mais usada e completa.
- [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler)
- [A New Task Scheduler Class Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2407/A-New-Task-Scheduler-Class-Library-for-NET)
- [Chroniton](https://github.com/leosperry/Chroniton)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Fiz o uso da biblioteca Quartz e funcionou. e para quem não sabe usar apos um estudo achei um artigo otimo e simples para começar a aprender e realizar algo segue: [http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net]