# Disparar método 5 segundos após execução do anterior

Tags: c#, timer

Como colocar um timer para que após 5 do envio do comando `EnvDados` seja realizado o envio do comando  `NovoEnvio`, isso dentro do mesmo mesmo método?

```
IPAddress[] IPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);
Socket s = new Socket(
               AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
               SocketType.Stream, 
               ProtocolType.Tcp);

s.Connect(IPs[0], port);

// Recebe o Retorno após a conexão
byte[] buffer = new byte[60];
s.Receive(buffer);

// Envia um novo Comando
byte[] EnvDados = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ordem + "\n");
s.Send(EnvDados);

// Após 5 segundos enviar novo comando
byte[] NovoEnvio = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ordem + "\n");
s.Send(NovoEnvio);
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 framework 4.0

Comment: Veja se alguma te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30601/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87293/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86015/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa de um timer pra isso.

#### Se estiver usando C# 6

```
s.Send(EnvDados);

await Task.Sleep(5000);

byte[] NovoEnvio = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ordem + "\n");
s.Send(NovoEnvio);
```

#### Em versões anteriores

Obviamente, isso vai travar a thread que o método estiver rodando, mas, em alguns casos, isso não é problema.

```
s.Send(EnvDados);

Thread.Sleep(5000);

byte[] NovoEnvio = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ordem + "\n");
s.Send(NovoEnvio);
```